PostgreSQL - how to implement my own casting from text to numeric
I need to write casting from text to numeric to accept values in single brackets as negative.
Example:
'(15)'::numeric should return -15.
Creating a domain and writing a cast function would be perfect, '(15)'::accountant_numeric but it is not possible to write a cast for domain.
I am not a superuser so I cannot create a scalar type.
What would be the best way to do it?
PostgreSQL version 13.

why not create your won type https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html

I am not a superuser and I do not own types text nor numeric.
I would need to create a composite type.
Is it the best solution?

You have conflicting requirements here: (a) "I want to alter core behaviour not have custom functions" and (b) "I do not want/cannot get permissions required to change core behaviour". You will need to drop one of (a) or (b)

You could store a negative value using -, the default in most applications. Just update your current content, change the datatype and you're done.

Postgres 13 has PL-PGSQL functions, I would use it.
Do you have any specific reason to use typecasting rather than invoking custom function
select parenthesis_to_negative('(15)') ?

Yes, uniformness of design.
I use it for validation of input data that are all text.
Each column of the input has defined type to which it should be cast.
It works everywhere with exception of numeric, where I need to apply this change to standard behavior.

I see 2 solutions:

write an if only for numeric
write dummy functions for all the other types.
I do not like either.


I agree the custom data type is definitely better and cleaner solution than custom function. If insufficient privileges stay in your way, I feel you should concentrate on "non-developer" work such as gaining access or explaining why is it necessary, rather than search for (potentially hacky) workarounds.

You can add your own casts, but adding casts on system types is often not a good idea, since it can lead to ambiguities and errors.
